# Mongo Java Replica Set - Can't find master

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I'm having problem with connecting to Mongo Replica Set in production. Replica Set has master on one machine, and secundary + arbiter on other machine.

When I run my application locally it connects and uses Replica Set properly. I'm using Windows OS.

Mongo URI is like this:

mongodb://192.168.2.95:20000,192.168.2.96:20000/testDatabase

I'm using Java Driver 2.10.1.

When I deploy application in production server, It can't use replica set. Error is "can't find master".

When I change mongo URI to use single node, like this:

mongodb://192.168.2.95:20000/testDatabase

then it works!

What's the problem? I have search the web and I found few people with similar problem but I didn't found any proper solution...

Comment: From the command line run `mongo --host 192.168.2.95:20000  --eval "printjson(rs.status())"`. This will dump the current status of your replica set. My guess is that it's not configured properly  (i.e. there is no primary). If this is the case , then the single node URI is working because you are not doing any updates (creates,deletes) and you are not using the default read preference (**primary**) or you are calling `slaveOk()`. If there is a primary, then update the question with the `rs.status()` output.

Comment: or it works because the machine you think is primary is just a stand-alone mongod and you hadn't configured replica set successfully on it at all.

Comment: Replica Set is configured properly and it works. I fixed the problem - production machine couldn't resolve IP address :S (DNS resolving) That's weird because I set up IP address, not symbolic names.